# mapping values are not allowed in this context in "<unicode string>"

Tags: unicode, yaml, schema, zsh, dbt

In my loop, I run a dbt command and save the output to a .yml file. The following command works and generates a schema in my `.yml` file accurately:

```
for file in models/l30_mart/*.sql; do
    table=$(basename "$file" .sql)
    dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": \"$table\"}" > test.yml
done
```

However, in the example above, I am saving the `test.yml` file in the root directory. When I try to save the file in another path for example `models/l30_mart/test.yml` like this, it doesn't work:

```
for file in models/l30_mart/*.sql; do
    table=$(basename "$file" .sql)
    dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": \"$table\"}" > models/l30_mart/test.yml
done
```

In this case, when I open the `test.yml`file, I see this:

```
12:06:42  Running with dbt=1.0.1
12:06:43  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  The schema file at models/l30_mart/test.yml is invalid because no version is specified. Please consult the documentation for more information on schema.yml syntax:
  
  https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/schemayml-files
```

What am I missing out on?

If I try something like this to save different files with the extracted tablename variable as the filename, it also doesn't work:

```
for file in models/l30_mart/*.sql; do
    table=$(basename "$file" .sql)
    dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": \"$table\"}" >  models/l30_mart/$table.yml
done
```

In this case, the files either have this output:

```
20:39:44  Running with dbt=1.0.1
20:39:45  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  The schema file at models/l30_mart/**firsttable.yml** is invalid because no version is specified. Please consult the documentation for more information on schema.yml syntax:
  
  https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/schemayml-files
```

or this (eg in the **secondtablename.yml** file):

```
20:39:48  Running with dbt=1.0.1
20:39:49  Encountered an error:
Parsing Error
  Error reading dbt_4flow: l30_mart/firstablename.yml - Runtime Error
    Syntax error near line 2
    ------------------------------
    1  | 20:39:44  Running with dbt=1.0.1
    2  | 20:39:45  Encountered an error:
    3  | Compilation Error
    4  |   The schema file at models/l30_mart/firsttablename.yml is invalid because no version is specified. Please consult the documentation for more information on schema.yml syntax:
    5  |   
    
    Raw Error:
    ------------------------------
    mapping values are not allowed in this context
      in "<unicode string>", line 2, column 31
```

Note that the **secondtablename.yml** mentions the **firsttablename.yml**.

Comment: Can you provide the first few lines of the yml file in question?

Comment: There's supposed to be no .yml file before I run the code. After running the code, the content of the .yml file is basically the output of the commands I run, which I have already pasted above @JoshD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `dbt` but the explanation that seems likely is that `dbt` for some reason parses all `*.yml` files in that target directory when you call it. Since the shell opens the pipe to the `*.yml` file before calling `dbt`, the file already exists (but initially empty) when `dbt` is called. Since `dbt` expects the file to contain a `version`, you get an error.

To check whether this assessment is correct, write into a temporary file:

```
for file in models/l30_mart/*.sql; do
    target_file=$(mktemp)
    table=$(basename "$file" .sql)
    dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": \"$table\"}" > $target_file
    mv $target_file models/l30_mart/test.yml
done
```

(Be aware of [mktemp shenanigans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30091/fix-or-alternative-for-mktemp-in-os-x) if you're using macOS)

Edit: Since `dbt` seems to be affected by the files existing, you can also try to generate *all* files and move them into the correct directory afterwards:

```
target_dir=$(mktemp -d)
for file in models/l30_mart/*.sql; do
    table=$(basename "$file" .sql)
    dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": \"$table\"}" > $target_dir/$table.yml
done
mv $target_dir/*.yml models/l30_mart/
rmdir $target_dir
```

Comment: @Jbd That message is just a symptom of one of the present YAML files containing some error message instead of the expected data. Try doing `set -e` to stop at the first error, and ensure that no YAML files of previous runs still exist.

Comment: where do I do set -e exactly? ```dbt: error: unrecognized arguments: set -e```. If instead of the ```mv target_file```, I just do ```cat $target_file```,  I see my correct, desired output printed on the terminal. This means that the output saved in the target file is correct for all files and there's no error. However, the problem arises when i put the ```test.yml```file in the loop. I realized that uptil the first loop run, the output is correct. However, in the next loop run there's an error written to the file. Probably because it parses all .yml files

Comment: @Jbd `set -e` is a shell feature, do it before the loop. It instructs the shell to stop if a command has a non-zero exit code. The content of the first file is very likely to cause the error in the second, can you share it?

Comment: @Jbd also check the edit in my answer.

Comment: @Jbd The script never `cd`s into the `target_dir`. It is created and files are written into it, but it doesn't become the working directory. Are you sure you have executed the script in the same directory as before?

Comment: ah i was copying your command where you had written ```130``` instead of ```l30```. However, I am still unable to ```mv```. I get this error ```mv $target_dir/*.yml models/130_mart/
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory```

Comment: @Jbd Sorry I misread the `l30`. I updated the code in both places (also in the `mv` which causes your error).

Comment: Can you also take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572461/save-command-output-to-a-file-without-timestamp-info