# save command output to a file without timestamp info

Tags: yaml, schema, zsh, dbt

If I run this command on my terminal (https://hub.getdbt.com/dbt-labs/codegen/latest/):

```
dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": "bookings"}"
```

I get an output that looks like this:

```
12:53:32  Running with dbt=1.0.1
12:53:34  version: 2

models:
  - name: bookings
    description: ""
    columns:
      - name: booking_id
        description: ""

      - name: masterclient_id
        description: ""
```

I want to save it to a file. If I do this:

```
dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": "bookings"}"  > test.yml
```

this also gets saved to the output:

```
12:53:32  Running with dbt=1.0.1
12:53:34
```

While my desired output is just this:

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: bookings
    description: ""
    columns:
      - name: booking_id
        description: ""

      - name: masterclient_id
        description: ""
```

How can I get rid of the extra time stamp info in the beginning and then save the remaining output in a file?

Comment: This future feature of the codegen package will solve this issue https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-codegen/issues/56

Comment: How exactly can I use this in my run_operation command? I am using neither log nor print. I tried using the ```--quiet```flag that is mentioned in the comment but it is unrecognized ```dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --quiet --args "{\"model_name\": \"$table\"}" > $target_dir/$table.yml```@JoshD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're confident that the output is always structured with those exact two timestamps, you can do:

```sh
dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml \
  --args "{\"model_name\": \"bookings\"}" \
  | tail -n +2 | sed '1 s/[0-9:]* *//'
```

`tail -n +2` removes the first line. The `sed` command removes the timestamp and following whitespace from the second (now first) line.

A quick look at [the relevant dbt docs](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-codegen/tree/0.6.0/#generate_model_yaml-source) yields

> 3. The YAML for a base model will be logged to the command line

So it doesn't seem that you can instruct `dbt` directly to output the YAML data *without* the logging timestamps.

Comment: I tried this in my loop ```dbt run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": \"$table\"}" | tail -n +2 | sed '1 s/[0-9:]* *//' > $target_dir/$table.yml``` Looks like I am making a syntax errror because currently I get errors in my files: ```Raw Error:
  while scanning a simple key
    in "<unicode string>", line 10, column 1```

Comment: @Jbd That's a YAML error, you need to show the YAML it originates from. Possibly the output had more log lines than the one you show, thus not all were removed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can run with `--quiet` flag to omit the logging timestamps, dbt does support this; the flag needs to go right after `dbt` command:

```
dbt --quiet run-operation generate_model_yaml --args "{\"model_name\": "bookings"}"  > test.yml
```